# Quantifying polygon changes between shape layers in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area, comparison

I have a map with two shape layers from different years, which are made up of habitat polygons, and are the same shape other than changes to the areas of these habitats.

How do I get a table of the habitat changes by area from one year to the next? I want to know how much of habitat A has become habitat B, etc.

I have made a union of both shape files, but don't know where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a symbology based on 2 fields (habitat type from shapefile A and habitat type form shapefile B).

In the Layer properties of your intersect layer, click the Symbology tab. Select 'Multiple Attributes - Quantity by Category' as symbology type in the left panel (1), then select the 2 fields holding the habitat information (2), and click the 'Add All Values' button to get all combinations of attribute values (3).

[image]